# Closing all open issues in Crashlytics at once?

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

I want to close all open issues at once in Firebase:Crashlytics? I have hundreds of them and that’s a pain entering and closing one by one?

Answer (score 36):

Paul from Crashlytics here. That's a good question and unfortunately, it's not currently possible. However, I can definitely let the team know that you'd like this feature!

Comment: Awesome and thanks a lot. Btw what case my scenario was: implemented crashlytics in first stage of developing my app, and forget to silence it correctly. So when I open the crashlytics there were many many bugs need to be closed, there catch me every time .

Comment: @Buser I need this feature too, did you manage to work on this feature?

Comment: yeah some type of batch operations / select all would be great

Comment: while we're at it, a "Comment + Close" option instead of separate buttons - like a Github issue - would be rad

Comment: @buser do you know if this is comming soon?

Comment: I would like to have an option to close all crashes which haven't happened since x release.

Comment: Still this feature is not available. Frustrating!

Comment: It'd be of great help if this could be implemented soon.

Comment: Is there any news on this?

Comment: Please add this features, very frustrating to close one by one for my outdated releases.

Comment: Same, recently had an episode of having crashlytics enabled during debugging, now there's a number of irrelevant issues to close :P

Comment: 2,5 years later and this is still an issue

Comment: Would still like to have this! I'm currently in the process of manually closing each individual crash that was generated while the app was in early development... still have 75 different entries to go. Serious pain in the...

Comment: 3.5 years now, still very much need it, especially for my dev builds

Comment: 5.5 years now, still very much needed